# Behaviour of zrangebyscore with string min and max in jedis

Tags: redis, jedis

The method signature of the function I want to know about in Jedis is as follows:

```
Set<String> zrangeByScore(String key,
                          String min,
                          String max,
                          int offset,
                          int count)
```

The Redis documentation has information about this method with double min and max but I could not find any description anywhere of how it works with String min and max, along with the offset and count.

Can I please have a description of this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source for the Jedis library is open-source, so you can check it out from Github and look yourself. It's a pretty straightforward library to understand, so I'd recommend it.

https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/blob/master/src/main/java/redis/clients/jedis/Jedis.java

If you follow the `zrangeByScore` method which takes `double` `min` and `max` the library actually converts the `double` arguments to `String`s, before converting the `String` to a `byte[]` and sending to Redis. The method which takes `String` `min` and `max` converts them straight to `byte[]`. If you look *all* arguments are actually sent to Redis as `byte[]`

So the String version is exactly the same as the `double` version (it is still expecting you to use number for min and max), it's just there as a convenience.